# Coherent sheaves, Serre’s theorem and ext groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, category-theory, coherent-sheaves, graded-modules

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over an algebraically closed field $k$ (if necessary we assume that $\operatorname{ch}(k)=0$).
Let $O_X(1)$ be a very ample invertible sheaf on $X$.

Then, the category $\operatorname{Coh}(X)$ of coherent sheaves on $X$ is equivalent to the category $\operatorname{qgr}(A):= \operatorname{gr}(A)/{\operatorname{tor}(A)}$, where $A:= \bigoplus_{i \geq 0} H^0(X,O_X(1))$ and $\operatorname{qgr}(A)$ is the Serre quotient category of the category $\operatorname{gr}(A)$ of finitely generated graded $A$-modules by the category $\operatorname{tor}(A)$ of finitely generated torsion $A$-modules.

Then, we have an isomorphism
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Hom}_{O_X}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \operatorname{Hom}_{\operatorname{gr}(A)}(\Gamma_{*}(\mathcal{F})_{\geq n}, \Gamma_{*}(\mathcal{G})_{\geq n})\\
 &(= \operatorname{Hom}_{\operatorname{qgr}(A)}(\Gamma_{*}(\mathcal{F}),\Gamma_{*}(\mathcal{G}))),
\end{align}
where $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G} \in \operatorname{Coh}(X)$ and  $\Gamma_{*}(\mathcal{F}):=\bigoplus_{i} H^0(X,\mathcal{F}(i))$, $\Gamma_{*}(\mathcal{G}):=\bigoplus_{i} H^0(X,\mathcal{G}(i))$.
$\Gamma_{*}(\mathcal{F})_{\geq n}$ also means the truncation of $M$ at the degree $n$.
Moreover, we have
$$
\operatorname{Ext}^i_{O_X}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \operatorname{Ext}^i_{\operatorname{gr}(A)}(\Gamma_{*}(\mathcal{F})_{\geq n}, \Gamma_{*}(\mathcal{G})_{\geq n})
$$
according to Proposition 4.3.3 (a) in [Ciocan-Fontanine and Kapranov - Derived Quot schemes](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9905174).

On the other hand, the functor
$$
\Gamma_{*} : \operatorname{Coh}(X) \rightarrow  \operatorname{gr}(A)
$$
has a right adjoint
$$
\tilde{-}:\operatorname{gr}(A) \rightarrow  \operatorname{Coh}(X),\  M \mapsto \tilde{M}.
$$
Then, for any $M \in \operatorname{gr}(A)$, there exists $m \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $\Gamma_{*}(\tilde{M})_{\geq m} \simeq M_{\geq m}$ in $\operatorname{gr}(A)$.

(Perhaps, the following relative theory is not necessarily in my questions.)
We also have relative statement (Section 3.1 of [The derived moduli space of stable sheaves](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.1884)) :
Let $S$ be a noetherian scheme. Then, we have a functor
\begin{align*}
\Gamma_{*} : \operatorname{Coh}(X \times_k S)& \rightarrow  \{\text{the category of graded  coherent sheaves of $A \otimes_k \mathcal{O}_S$-modules} \} \\
&\hat{\mathcal{F}} \mapsto \oplus_i {\pi_{S}}_*(\hat{\mathcal{F}} \otimes \pi_{X}^*\mathcal{O}_X(i)).
\end{align*}
There exists the right adjoint functor
$$
\tilde{-} :  \{\text{the category of graded  coherent sheaves of $A \otimes_k \mathcal{O}_S$-modules} \} \rightarrow  \operatorname{Coh}(X \times_k S) .
$$

**Questions** :
Are the following true ?

1. For each $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G} \in \operatorname{Coh}(X)$, and each $i \geq 0$, there exists $m$ such that
   $$
   \operatorname{Ext}^i_{O_X}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}) = \operatorname{Ext}^i(\Gamma_{*}(\mathcal{F})_{\geq m}, \Gamma_{*}(\mathcal{G})_{\geq m}). 
   $$
2. Let $S$ be a noetherian scheme over $k$.
   Let $\hat{\mathcal{F}},\hat{\mathcal{G}} \in \operatorname{Coh}(X \times_k S)$ be flat families over $S$.
   Then, there exists $m \geq 0$ such that for any $i \geq 0$ and any $s \in S$,
   $$
   \operatorname{Ext}^i_{O_X}(\hat{\mathcal{F}}_s,\hat{\mathcal{G}}_s) = \operatorname{Ext}^i_{\operatorname{gr}(A)}(\Gamma_{*}(\hat{\mathcal{F}}_s)_{\geq m}, \Gamma_{*}(\hat{\mathcal{G}}_s)_{\geq m}),
   $$
   where
   $\hat{\mathcal{F}}_s$ is the restriction of $\hat{\mathcal{F}}$ to the fiber $\{s\} \times_S (X \times_k S) \simeq X$.
   (In Prop 4.3.3 (b) of the above reference, a similar result appears, but I am not sure that it is true. At least, I think $m$ is dependent on $i$ in the question.)
3. Let $S$ be a noetherian scheme.
   Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a flat family of finitely generated graded $A$-modules over $S$ (so that $\mathcal{M}$ is vector bundle on $S$).
   Then, there exists $m \geq 0$ s.t. for any $s \in S$,
   $$
   \Gamma_{*}(\tilde{\mathcal{M}_s})_{\geq m} \simeq (\mathcal{M}_s)_{\geq m} \text{ as graded modules},
   $$
   where $\mathcal{M}_s$ is the  restriction of $\mathcal{M}$ to the fiber $\{s \} \times_S S \simeq \operatorname{Spec}(k)$ (so that $\mathcal{M}_s$ is a graded $A$-module).

Any  comment is welcome.

(Please let me know if any conditions are missing.)

The same question is in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/460282/317253).

**Edit(2023,12/15)** :
Some notations are changed. Question 3 is added.
I also added more information about the adjoint functor of $\Gamma_*$, a relative theory of the Serre's theorem and question 2.

**Edit(2024,1/29)**
In Ciocan-Fontanine and Kapranov’s paper, they tried to construct derived quot schemes.
However, their construction is not correct.
Actually, they point out a problem(cf. [derived quot stacks I](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.03021),[derived quot stacks II](https://arxiv.org/abs/2312.02815)).
In addition, the authors in “derived quot stacks” gave the answer to the problem.
On the other hand, they did not mention our questions.